# Easiest way to check if value is one of a set of values in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, enums, set

What is the easiest way to check if a value is one of a set of values?

eg.

```
if (new List<CustomerType>{CustomerType.Overseas, CustomerType.Interstate}.Contains(customerType)) 
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: You may consider `HashSet` instead of `List`, but what is wrong with your sample?

Comment: @GrantWinney: is there a shorter way?

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes there is a faster way.  HashSet is a faster collection for contains.

Comment: @GrantWinney So he asked for easiest.  Why not go with a solution as easy and faster?

Comment: @GrantWinney: what about LINQ?

Comment: @GrantWinney: could the LINQ keyword `in` be used?

Comment: @GrantWinney: could a `LINQ query` be used?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Just how is List is easier that HashSet?  Really a List may be faster?

Comment: @Blam after verifying my timing `List` turned out to be much slower than I initially measured so `List` can barely beat/match `HashSet` with 0-2 items (code posted below) - so `HashSet` is better choice. As usual - never guess performance numbers... Thanks for fun.

Comment: @GrantWinney Both List and HashSet have Contains methods that are not LINQ extensions.  They work without using Systems.linq;

Answer (score 5):

Why would you create a List?
Why would you create it every time?

HashSet is the fastest contains.

```
private HashSet<CustomerType> CustomerTypes = new HashSet<CustomerType>() {CustomerType.Overseas, CustomerType.Interstate};
if (CustomerTypes.Contains(customerType))
{ }
```

This has had some discussion so more.
Considering speed.
If you are only going to evaluate once (or inline) then this will win

```
if (customerType == CustomerType.Overseas || customerType == CustomerType.Interstate) 
{
    // code here
}
```

If you are going to evaluate multiple times then HashSet will win.
Create the HashSet once at the start of the application.
Don't create the HashSet (or List or Array) each time.

For small number a List or Array may win but Contains is O(n) so response will degrade with longer list.

HashSet.Contains is O(1) so response will not degrade with with larger n.

Comment: +1. Consider removing questions from the answer and convert them to statements...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What part of use HashSet and a code sample is not a clear answer statement?

Comment: I'm awfully unclear today... I mean something like: "Why would you create a List?" -> "Use HashSet as it is explicitly designed for such operations and ....". "Why would you create it every time?" -> "Unless you need comparison in exactly one place/one time it is better to ...".

Answer (score 0):

Well you can loop it and see if it works. Make an array of the kinds of things you want then use a for loop and compare them.

```
CustomerType[] customers = {new CustomerType("Overseas"), new CustomerType("Interstate")};
public CustomerType(int id, String type){
this.type = type;
}
public String getType(){return type;}
```

then you can scan the types

```
for(int i = 0; i < CustomerTypes.customers.length; i++){
if(CustomerTypes.customers[i].getType == "Overseas"){
//CODE
}
else if(CustomerTypes.customers[i].getType == "Interstate"){
//CODE
}else{
//CODE "UNKNOWN CUSTOMER TYPE"
}
}
```

Im pretty sure this is what your asking. But if not please clarify and i will be glad to give more help!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer: Comparison of `HashSet` vs. `List` for the `Contains` - TL;DR; prefer - `HashSet`.

Guess: `List` is simpler, so for small number of items it should be faster than `HashSet` so using `new List<EnumType>{EnumType.Value1, EnumType.Value2}` is as good as the same code with `HashSet`.

Reality: `Contains` for `List` is much slower than one would expect (compared to direct iteration over `Array` which beats `HashSet` up to 10 items), so `List` can beat `HashSet` when either number of items is 0-2 or first choice in the `List` is significantly more common than other choices out of very small (<5?) number of values.

Measurement:

```
    static void ComapreListAndHashSet()
    {
        bool found = false;
        var length = 10000000;
        const int searchValue = -1;

        for (int size = 0; size < 15; size++)
        {
            var list = Enumerable.Range(1, size).ToList();
            var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(list);

            var timeForList = new Stopwatch();
            timeForList.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                found = found & (list.Contains(searchValue));
            }
            timeForList.Stop();

            var timeForHash = new Stopwatch();
            timeForHash.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                found = found & hashSet.Contains(searchValue);
            }
            timeForHash.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0},\t{1},\t{2}", hashSet.Count,
                timeForList.ElapsedMilliseconds, timeForHash.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Size:   List:   HashSet(ms):
0,      120,    155
1,      163,    194
2,      203,    189
3,      250,    189
4,      294,    188
5,      332,    188
```